# trying navigation null is not on object evaluating C.State

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a simple react native navigation but I get an error.

I see the example in facebook:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

I need make an app with login, send data to server, retrieve data and search but I don't know how make a good navigation screen.

But this causes an error, can somebody help me?

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import App from './sections/main';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './home';
import ProfileScreen from './profile';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import bgSrc from '../images/fondo3.jpg';
import logoImg from '../images/icontime1.png';
import plusImg from '../images/plus.png';
import editImg from '../images/iconedit1.png';

export default class home extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Bienvenido',
    };
    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={bgSrc} style={styles.picture}>
                    <Button
                        title="Go to Jane's profile"
                        onPress={() => navigate('Profile', {name: 'Jane'})}
                    />
                </ImageBackground>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

and profile.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import bgSrc from '../images/fondo3.jpg';
import logoImg from '../images/icontime1.png';
import plusImg from '../images/plus.png';
import editImg from '../images/iconedit1.png';

export default class profile extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Profile',
    };
    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return (
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
              <ImageBackground source={bgSrc} style={styles.picture}>
                  <Button
                      title="Go to Jane's Home"
                      onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
                  />
              </ImageBackground>
          </ScrollView>
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: why you are not exporting home.js and profile.js???

Comment: i need add "export default" to home js and profile js?

Comment: i add export default  but error continue :/

Comment: did you try to restart project in your terminal?

Comment: how can do this?